Converting sentences to a value
I have been trying to convert the words in a variable in Stata (e.g: Variable1 contains yes or no, and I want to make yes =1 and no=0).
I'm using the method of label define but it messes up the conversion and I'm not sure how does the encode command works too.

This works:
clear 
input str3 whatever 
"yes"
"no"
end 

label def wanted 1 "yes" 0 "no"

encode whatever, gen(wanted) label(wanted)

list 

list, nolabel 

Output:
. clear 

. input str3 whatever 

      whatever
  1. "yes"
  2. "no"
  3. end 

. 
. label def wanted 1 "yes" 0 "no"

. 
. encode whatever, gen(wanted) label(wanted)

. 
. list 

     +-------------------+
     | whatever   wanted |
     |-------------------|
  1. |      yes      yes |
  2. |       no       no |
     +-------------------+

. 
. list, nolabel 

     +-------------------+
     | whatever   wanted |
     |-------------------|
  1. |      yes        1 |
  2. |       no        0 |
     +-------------------+

Notes: The label define method works well if and only if you have exact equality of strings and value labels. It won't do what you want if any of these complications occurs:

Leading and/or trailing spaces.

Upper case where lower case is defined, or the other way round.

Other characters.


For "contains" you may need something else like
gen WANTED = cond(strpos(lower(whatever), "yes"), 1, cond(strpos(lower(whatever), "no"), 0, .)) 

which can re-written more slowly
gen WANTED = 1 if strpos(lower(whatever), "yes") 
replace WANTED = 0 if strpos(lower(whatever), "no") 

If this doesn't explain enough, we need to see
an example of the data you have
the code you tried, exactly
the error(s) you experienced.

Thank you so much for helping me out. I was trying this code exactly.  label define house_walls_lb 0 "other" 1 "wood (both constructed and harnessed, hard and light wood materials)" 2 "masonry (stones, bricks, cement, concrete, septum etc."  and encode house_walls, gen(walls_numeric) label(house_walls_lb) but the error message given to me was '. encode house_walls, gen(new_house_walls) label(house_walls_lb)
not possible with numeric variable`

If your variable is already numeric, then encode is not needed. encode is for mapping string variables to numeric. From the information you give, I suspect that your solution is just to follow label define with label values. If not, then please edit your question to give a data example as code as in my answer. See also help dataex in Stata.
